# Updateable Recordset with Count Field - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not an SQL Expert. Maybe what I'm trying to do here isn't even possible.

I'm trying to get an updateable recordset that includes a field that is the result of an aggregate function.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT Contact.*, Count(OrderID) as CountOfOrders
FROM Contact INNER JOIN Order ON Order.ContactID = Contact.ContactID
WHERE ContactID = 1
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have an updateable recordset which includes an aggregate function.

Comment: @HansUp: not possible with a DAO recordset perhaps but doable with an ADO recordset. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the MSDataShape OLE DE provider *and* the OLE DB provider for Jet (or ACE) then it is indeed possible to create an updateable ADO recordset and `APPEND` a computed column based on a set function such as `COUNT()`. The resulting SQL-esque code would look more like this:

```
 SHAPE  {SELECT ContactID, ContactName FROM Contact} 
APPEND ({SELECT ContactID, OrderID FROM Orders} 
         RELATE ContactID TO ContactID
       ) As rsDetails, COUNT(rsDetails.OrderID) AS CountOfOrder
```

Here's a brief 'proof of concept': paste the following into any VBA module (e.g. use Excel), no references required, creates a new .mdb in your temp directory, creates the tables with data, to prove the recordset is updateable the `ContactName` value is changed and the recordset reopened to show it has indeed changed:

```
Sub ShapeAppendCount()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"

    Dim jeng
    Set jeng = CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine")
    jeng.RefreshCache .ActiveConnection

    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With

  Dim con
  Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  With con
    .ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=MSDataShape;" & _
        "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    .CursorLocation = 3
    .Open

    .Execute _
    "CREATE TABLE Contact (" & _
    "ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, " & _
    "ContactName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);"

    .Execute _
    "CREATE TABLE Orders (" & _
    "ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Contact (ContactID), " & _
    "OrderID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);"

    .Execute _
    "INSERT INTO Contact (ContactID, ContactName)" & _
    " VALUES (1, 'OneDayWhen');"

    .Execute _
    "INSERT INTO Orders (ContactID, OrderID)" & _
    " VALUES (1, 1);"

    .Execute _
    "INSERT INTO Orders (ContactID, OrderID)" & _
    " VALUES (1, 2);"

    Dim rs
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
      .CursorType = 2  ' adOpenDynamic
      .LockType = 4  ' adLockBatchOptimistic

      .Source = _
      " SHAPE {SELECT ContactID, ContactName FROM Contact} " & _
      "APPEND ({SELECT ContactID, OrderID FROM Orders} " & _
      "RELATE ContactID TO ContactID) As rsDetails, " & _
      " COUNT(rsDetails.OrderID) AS CountOfOrder"

      Set .ActiveConnection = con
      .Open

      .Fields("ContactName").Value = "Pink Cat"

      .UpdateBatch

      MsgBox .GetString
      .Close
    End With

    With rs
      .Source = _
      "SELECT ContactID, ContactName FROM Contact"

      Set .ActiveConnection = con
      .Open

      MsgBox .GetString
      .Close

    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I obviously MUST get into data shaping!

Comment: The MSDataShape provider is extremely problematic and fussy. I tried to start using it back in the early days of A2000, and ran into all sorts of problems. It's the provider that allows non-updatable SELECTs to be updated, for instance, because with SQL Server it goes directly to the base tables. This can wreak havoc with your security, and because of all these problems, I threw it out as a useful tool. MS appears to have done the same, as it's the main component between the ADP and SQL Server, and they've been deprecating that for about 5 years.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "This can wreak havoc with your security, and because of all these problems, I threw it out as a useful tool." With effect from ACE, the Access Team also threw out security as a useful tool, specifically the user-level variety. But seriously, I'm not convinced by your assertions: if the MSDataShape did expose a security loophole then we'd all know about it. I don't suppose you'd like to post code to prove your point, but if you do feel, free to edit my answer.

Comment: You don't remember Steve Jorgensen's series of posts discovering the problems with the way ADO bypasses your secured views to go direct to the data tables? My understanding is that the capabilities used by ADO are provided by the data shape component, but it was so long ago I could be misremembering. Your jab at ACE and the removal of ULS from one of its file formats is unworthy of you as it's just a cheap shot, since it's exactly the opposite kind of problem from the one I'm referring to.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: sorry, I don't even remember Steve Jorgensen. The big question is, did it receive proper peer review? To use an analogy, it no doubt sticks in your mind that Alan Browne once said the infamous '`DECIMAL` sort bug' yielded all kinds of odd behaviour. Fact is, most of it was unreproducible and the ill effects not as severe as reported (i.e. biased). No one seems to remember me refuting it every other week. But I'm not bitter :)

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: as regards your last sentence, I'm truly touched. But let's no take life too seriously, eh? I'm honouring a great tradition of British satire. Your sentence ("This can wreak havoc with your security...") was ambiguous and I couldn't resist the opportunity to protest about what I see as the dumbing down of ACE. Seriously, how else can the likes of me fight the power?

Comment: Steve's problems were confirmed by others in the Access newsgroups. That's sufficient peer review for me. Perhaps there was some kind of workaround, but I don't think there was. And MS tacitly badmouths MSDataShape in describing why it now deprecates ADPs in favor of MDBs (it's implied in the mushmouthed section about the intermediate layers between the ADP and the SQL Server).

Comment: On the Decimal bugs, there WERE problems in the initial implementation, not least of which the fact that it was implemented differently in the Access UI than in DDL (and that the DDL for it wouldn't run except in ADO at the time it was introduced). For most of those of us who actually use ACCESS qua ACCESS, this was sufficient reason to avoid the data type. And I still do, but it's not been any hardship, since I haven't needed it.